# How to remove current theme customizations

Tags: themes

How can I delete my current theme and all its customizations so that I can use a new theme from scratch? In other words, how can I use a new theme without it loading the old theme's customizations?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "customization"? Modifying the theme's PHP, or modifying some settings the theme creates? Most themes do not clean up after themselves when they are deactivated or deleted. So for many themes, there is no easy way to flush their data. This is actually a good thing, if you want to switch back and forth between themes, but it forces you to pay attention to what you install on your system. If there is no content, you could start with a new database, that would certainly reset any theme options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an unedited copy of the theme directory?

If you do, and just want to just start from 'scratch' you can just remove the theme that you are using from the wp-content>>themes directory and replace it with a new one.

If you don't have an unadulterated copy to reload into the directory you would have to try and feel out what has been altered... which would be a mess I imagine.

Comment: I did delete the current theme from themes directory but the new theme loaded some of my old customizations which messed up the site. Will try your suggestion of using an unedited copy of the theme directory and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found two solutions that worked and allowed me to reset the wordpress theme and restore it to default status: (1) using mysql to update options table; and (2) simply uploading a fresh copy of the theme's functions.php file